# Is there a command to remove all of one type of block in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm making a Minecraft map and it involves a lot of removing of certain blocks. Is there a vanilla Minecraft command to remove all blocks of one type in a world? If so, how would I use it?

For example: All different colors of wool spread around a world. And I only want to remove the white ones. How would I do that with a command?

Comment: I imagine it would be possible for different *types* of block, but not so much for varieties, like different colours of wool. Some commands don't quite support damage values being used.

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna just keep this short and say yep. Use -

`/fill [X1] [Y1] [Z1] [X2] [Y2] [Z2] [Block To Remove] replace air`

Comment: Its actually /fill [X1] [Y1] [Z1] [X2] [Y2] [Z2] air replace [Block To Remove]. I tried that and it worked. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: `replace` is not a command for block minecraft:air (or whatever)

Comment: This worked: /fill [X1] [Y1] [Z1] [X2] [Y2] [Z2] air 0 replace [Block To Remove] https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/fill_replace_water.php

Comment: 10/10 arguments are definitely in the correct order. Would buy again. https://i.imgur.com/exfESG1.png